# GPT partition table problem: Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, uefi, gpt

I hope you guys will help me get through this situation I have gotten myself into.

I bought a new samsung ultra book running windows 8. I knew going into the purchase that I wanted to ditch windows 8 and install Ubuntu and Windows 7 due to using this pc to build android and android apps.

I used `gparted` and deleted the partitions and installed Ubuntu on a separate partition without much grief. But now I can't get windows 7 installed on the other. I get a strange msg about GPT partition system or something.

From my understanding that is due to a new bios system and safe boot. 
I disabled safe boot but still can't get the install. If someone wise could assist me I would be very happy.

A second option would be to run a virtual machine and operate windows 7 that way but I'm having issues with that as well. I get a driver issue that tells me to SU `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv` update. But that gives a `command doesn't exist`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is really a Windows question.  You'd probably get better help on a Windows support site.  A couple of observations though: Only 64 bit Windows 7 can boot from a GPT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx and observation 2 is that installing Windows after Ubuntu will remove grub and the ability to boot Ubuntu until you re-install grub and configure it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The windows 7 installer does not install to EFI/GPT as default.

You need to put your Win7 installer disk's files onto a FAT32 formatted USB thumbdrive and copy an EFI bootloader into a specific location in order to get it to boot into the EFI-mode installer.

Follow this link:

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1840-installing-windows-from-usb-stick-to-a-gpt-drive

Also; this might help:

[How do I create a multiboot environment using LVM for your *buntu operating systems on a GPT formatted system drive, in a UEFI based system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226969/how-do-i-create-a-multiboot-environment-using-lvm-for-your-buntu-operating-syst/226982#226982)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Windows 7 supports GPT without EFI. Try to reinstall Ubuntu but format your drive as MBR instead of GPT. You should be able to install Windows 7 later without issues.

If you install Ubuntu before Windows you'll have to recover your GRUB installation after using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) or install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) in Windows.

Comment: I agree. I think windows 7 does not support GPT without EFI. I have tried and couldn't.