# Plans to automatically support existing GPT partitions during installation?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gpt

I have a desktop with a 2TB HD (Used for data) and a 120GB SSD currently used for Windows. The drives use GPT partition tables.

I wanted to install Ubuntu side by side with Windows but had a LOT of trouble getting GRUB to handle this setup and I finally gave up.

**My question: Are there plans for the Ubuntu installer to automatically handle [existing] GPT partition tables?**

I see a lot of people with similar problems to me, and as drives increase in size, this seems very necessary...

Thanks

/Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ubuntu has supported GPT since version 8.04 with both read/write and boot support ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Unix-class_operating_systems)).
- The GRUB 2 bootloader is included on all currently supported Ubuntu versions. GRUB 2 can accomodate traditional computer firmware such as BIOS as well as the newer EFI/UEFI standards. It is compatible with MBR, GPT and other partitioning tables ([Ubuntu WIKI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)).

So without an actual problem to answer: this is already the case. It might be possible to do it easier/with less hassle but it is already there for us. Mind you: the people that made this are not in the least helpful and do not have our interest at heart.

In the next release (13.04) is will be likely to be easier to use (as we expect with all of the software Ubuntu has) so be patient! We are in it for the long haul :D

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it was more a request for opinions about future development for GPT installations than for my specific problem. As Rich T. has mentioned, I will consider moving this post to the forums. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the way Ubuntu handles UEFI and GPT partitions has slowly and steadily improved over the last few years and I feel that this will continue. The Ubuntu installer itself has come on in leaps and bounds throughout the development cycle.

However, I think this is the wrong place to be asking for peoples' opinions about this stuff and the Ubuntu Forums might be a better venue. This site is better for answering specific technical questions. As I am writing this, I am looking at the guidelines, above my reply, which state:

> Your Answer
>
> Thanks for contributing an answer to Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange!
>
> Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!
>
> But avoid …
>
> Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
>     Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references
>     or personal experience.
>
> To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.

It is therefore very difficult to answer your question in any meaningful way.

Your lack of a specific question makes this very difficult, but I must say that you give up too easily!

That being said, I did my research and managed to make it work.

I actually wrote up a howto and posted it to this very site:

[How do I create a multiboot environment using LVM for your *buntu operating systems on a GPT formatted system drive, in a UEFI based system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226969/how-do-i-create-a-multiboot-environment-using-lvm-for-your-buntu-operating-syst)

Parts of it should be very useful in enabling you to do what you want.

Just remember that the big commercial Operating Systems, such as Windows, do not play nicely at all with other OSes and that Linux, flawed as it may be, is likely to provide you with the best options in dealing with this issue.

Stick with it!

Comment: Well I gave up because I had spent an entire day working on this problem and settled for just using ubuntu for app dev on my laptop instead. Thanks for the post - I will take a look at your link, and consider moving the thread to the ubuntu forums :)